# ASP.NET Authentication with Roles in IIS7 Integrated Mode for Static Content

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, integrated-pipeline-mode

I am experimenting with the integrated authentication mode for static content in IIS7. I followed the instructions in this article: https://web.archive.org/web/20210612113955/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/122408-1.aspx
It is working fine if I allow/deny access by login status (like in the article). However I want to allow/deny access based on roles (using the ASP.NET built in Roles Provider). When I put an allow rule for the role "Admin" in the web.config and deny rule for all other users I am not able to access the static files even when I login as an admin. The same folder contains non-static content (aspx pages) that are accessed just fine based on the Role Provider information.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us your web.config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `<system.webServer> <modules>` block:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
      <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
      <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" />
      <remove name="DefaultAuthentication" />
      <add name="DefaultAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule" />
      <remove name="RoleManager" />
      <add name="RoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The `RoleManager` bit is key, and it's not included in any of the online examples that I could find.  Without that, the user's role membership isn't initialized for static content, so role-based authorization will always fail.

(Disclaimer:  I've pieced this together myself based on my limited understanding of IIS, but it seems to work.)

**Edit** (in response to your comment):  Sorry, I don't know much about how RoleManager depends on other modules.  You can view the default IIS configuration by looking at `c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` (at least, that's the past on my Windows Vista machine) to see the order in which modules are loaded (note the use of [managedHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690693%28VS.90%29.aspx) by default to restrict RoleManager to non-static content), and MSDN covers [RoleManagerModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.rolemanagermodule.aspx) along with the rest of the modules in the [System.Web.Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt5ssstk.aspx) namespace, so you could probably find what you need there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I will make sure to test it these days.

Comment: It did work. Thanks again. Can you share a bit more info on how the RoleManager depends on the other modules. I noticed that if I don't remove/add the other modules there seems to be a null reference exception somewhere in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the most likely culprit is that the static files are not being processed by ASP.NET but being left up to IIS.

Does it work if you add a wildcard script mapping?

Comment: what do you suggest to add as a wildcard script mapping?
and if this is the case why does the authentication based on login status work but not the roles?